# My hard drive is not showing up

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, livecd, gparted

I am having some difficulties.

I just install a new ssd into my desktop and move my old sata drive to be 2nd.

I boot my computer and install windows 7 home premium on my new ssd.

Please note the 2nd hdd still have windows 7 install on it. I was thinking of reformatting it to just store my work projects.

The issue is I cannot see it, when windows starts even in disk manager.

The only place I see it, is in my bios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the second SATA channel is enabled in the BIOS; if it's not, the disk will probably show up in the BIOS as connected, but won't be exposed to the OS, which is pretty much exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: I am in the BIOS, not sure where i can find that setting.

Comment: I see SATA Port work from port 0-3 and its enabled

Comment: In that case I'd try it on a different SATA channel, or connect it to a USB-to-SATA adapter and see whether it shows up that way.

Comment: It was AHCI causing Havoc. My CD player dose not show up when its enabled and when its disabled my hdd is acting up.

Comment: Windows AHCI support still isn't all it could be, I suppose. Glad you found the culprit.